# A question about Texmaker settings

Tags: texmaker, texstudio, winedt

When having a number of files opened in Texmaker, at the top of editor pane, there is a drop down panel with the names of open documents in it. I prefer to have tabs of open documents at the top of editor pane, similar to Texstudio and Winedt. Is there a way that I can change this setting?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. You can get a list of open files with View --> List of opened files, but tabs doesn't appear to be an option.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. an answer? :-) As with most GUIs, the amount of customization you can do only goes so far (and in many cases, not at all).

Comment: Sadly there haven't been much possibilities of customizing this parts of TeXmaker and other forks of this Tool

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, I wasn't sure if I'd missed anything, I don't really use Texmaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Texmaker uses the same system than modern editors like xcode, kate, qtcreator which don't use anymore tabs.

The "list of opened files" option of the "View" menu works like tabs : if you click on an item, the editor for the corresponding file is displayed :

[image]